# Hide inherited base Object methods from intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Intellisense always displays the public methods/properties/variables. It also displays the base C# `object` variables. This is completely useless for 99.9% of situations and only serves as a distraction, cluttering intellisense with methods I don't plan to use. I don't care about `ToString`, `GetType`, `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, and when I do care, I don't need intellisense for them.

Example:

[image: Example Object]

Is there a way to hide the base C# `object` methods in Visual Studio intellisense?

Comment: These ones with the stars are from **IntelliCode**, you can try disable it.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 1):

For those ones with the star, you can disable them via disable this setting:

Tools -> Options -> IntelliCode -> General -> Promote likely items in IntelliSense completion lists(You can disable this, then the star selection will never shown.)

[image]

If you just don't want to see the methods here. You can use the filter below:

[image]

Comment: I know of this capability but, this does not accomplish what I want. This hides all methods, including the potentially useful ones. I just don't want to see `ToString`, `GetType`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in my autocomplete *ever*.

Comment: @NomenNescio I think VS doesn't have such built-in feature. :)